# Use QtConcurrent::map as a parallel for loop

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency

I want to have a for loop that executes in parallel with Qt and I came across [QtConcurrent::map](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#map). My current code looks like this:

```
QList<int> list;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) list.append(i);
auto future=QtConcurrent::map(list,[=](const int &i) {
    // do stuff in parallel
});
```

The QList looks like a waste of space (in code lines, and memory). Is there a (pseudo) iterator that just counts between 2 numbers? Is there a smarter solution within Qt?

Answer (score 1):

You can try QtConcurrent::run instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  QtConcurrent::run([=] {
    // do stuff in parallel
  });
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I would lose the single QFuture that keeps track of the progress of all elements